# Server side analytics using PHP-GA does not show up in my GA account.

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have been trying to use php-ga library to send server side ga event but, some how the data is not showing up on GA, using the GA js it works but from the server side this is not working. After trying for 2 days I am posting here.

Sample code:

```
$page = new GoogleAnalytics\Page("/dummypage.php");
$page->getTitle("Dummy page");
$tracker->trackPageview($page, $session, $visitor);
```

The logs printed by php-ga seems fine:

**Request: (Hiding the GA ID).**

September 2, 2014, 10:14 pmGET /__utm.gif?utmwv=5.2.5&utmac=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&utmhn=somethingawesome.in&utms=2&utmn=135498032&utmcc=__utma%3D80555669.599680152.1409676286.1409676286.1409676286.1%3B&utmp=%2Fdummypage.php&utmcs=-&utmr=-&utmip=127.0.0.1&utmul=&utmfl=-&utmje=-&utmhid=1974089052 HTTP/1.0^M

Host: www.google-analytics.com^M

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36^M
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1^M
Connection: close^M

**Response:**

September 2, 2014, 10:14 pmResponse = HTTP/1.0 200 OK^M
Pragma: no-cache^M
Expires: Wed, 19 Apr 2000 11:43:00 GMT^M
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jan 2004 19:51:30 GMT^M
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff^M
Content-Type: image/gif^M
Date: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 00:53:10 GMT^M
Server: Golfe2^M
Content-Length: 35^M
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate^M
Age: 316296^M
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic^M
^M

I am sure my GA ID is correct. 
Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just realized that it is working, just that strangely the events were not showing up in the real-time dashboard of GA (but are available in normal view).